# error in running Blackberry messenger sample application which is provided by BlackberryMessangerAPI?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

Hi I am facing a strange problem 
that I am testing a BlackberryMessanger sample application in my phone.
When I was running this application in simulator it show me an error like"uncaught exception net.rim.vm.missingnativeerror"
and when I was signing this application I got following error(following image) and signing complete 
after that i install this application in my phone 9780 os 6.0 ,it successfully installed 
when i was trying to run this it became hang 
i am following all instructions according to 
http://us.blackberry.com/developers/blackberrymessenger/
[image]please help me how to solve this issue

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i resolved my issue. In general when we add JAR file ,we put tic mark into the check box.
but here we dont put tic mark into check box.then we dont get any problem

Note:region exactly i dont know but it is working through this solution. If anybody explain the region ,we will appreciated.

IN GENERAL:

[image: WRONG IMAGE]

BUT WE HAVE TO CHANGE AS FOLLOWING:

[image: RIGHT IMAGE]

> ```
> NOTE:THIS SOLUTION ONLY FOR BBM SDK
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the red text claiming "NOT REGISTERED" in the status column seems a bit like your 'signing account' does is not configured to sign BBM features. The signing is made remotely at RIM servers and your account has to be marked as being-able-to-use-API-named-XXX. If I were you, I'd really listen to the message seen in "details" and simply as the RIM about that error and/or access to the API.